# Fody is throwing an error after installation in my MVVM WPF project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package, fody, fody-propertychanged

I am trying to build an app using WPF based on the MVVM project. While learning, I found it tedious to have to implement the getter/setter for every property to notify the view of a change. That is when I learn about [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)

I tried to install the package using the following 2 commands

```
Install-Package PropertyChanged.Fody
Update-Package Fody
```

During the `Install-Package PropertyChanged.Fody` step, I got the following warnings

> One or more packages could not be completely uninstalled: Fody.2.4.1.
>   Restart Visual Studio to finish uninstall.

Then During the `Update-Package Fody` step, I got the following warnings

> Uninstalling 'Fody 2.3.20'. Access to the path
>   'C:\WinProjects\Proj1\packages\Fody.2.3.20\netclassictask\Fody.dll' is
>   denied. Access to the path
>   'C:\WinProjects\Proj1\packages\Fody.2.3.20\netclassictask\FodyCommon.dll'
>   is denied. Access to the path 'Fody.dll' is denied. Successfully
>   uninstalled 'Fody 2.3.20'. One or more packages could not be
>   completely uninstalled: Fody.2.3.20. Restart Visual Studio to finish
>   uninstall.

I tried running Visual Studio as Admin but that also lead me to the same results.

Now, when I build this project I get the following error

> The "Fody.WeavingTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\WinProjects\Proj1\packages\Fody.2.4.1\build..\netclassictask\Fody.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.    WindowsClient

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can u raise an issue here https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues and include a solution that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 0):

I would first reboot your computer and then uninstall everything:

```
Get-Project -All | Uninstall-Package PropertyChanged.Fody -RemoveDependencies
Get-Project -All | Uninstall-Package Fody -RemoveDependencies
```

If necessary, repeat for both versions (Fody 2.3.20 and 2.4.1).

After you're done, install Fody again.
If uninstalling isn't enough, delete all Fody files from `C:\WinProjects\Proj1\packages`

Comment: I get the following error `Uninstall-Package : Unable to find package 'Fody' in 'Support'.`  `Support` is one my the projects on my solytion

Comment: Not a problem, it's perfectly normal if you don't use Fody in Support. Go on with the other steps.

Comment: When I remove `Get-Project -All |` from the command and run them I am able to remove the packages. I also delete the Fody folders from my packages folder manually. I installed the packages. When running the update I am still getting Access to path ...... is denied

Comment: Do those file exist? If so, right-click, properties, security tab, share with user "Everyone".

Comment: I just saw that you're missing something.
Run this in *NuGet*

`Install-Package Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core`

Comment: I get the following error Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core 15.5.180'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files

Comment: `Install-Package Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core -Version 15.1.548`

Comment: Same error still. I think the `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core` is part of .Net Core Not .Net 4.5.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165518/discussion-between-francesco-b-and-jaylen).

Comment: `Install-Package Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core -Version 14.3.0` should be ok with your version